# Using Freeswitch ESL Api answer a call from one sip remote softphone to another sip remote softphone using java

Tags: java, sip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

### I want to answer a call ringing from one sip remote softphone to another sip remote softphone using Freeswitch ESL API in java.

I tried, using the `uuid_answer` API command to answer a call while getting "Unique-ID" form `CHANNEL_CALLSTATE` Event,

```
EslMessage response = client.sendSyncApiCommand("uuid_answer",Event_Header.get("Unique-ID"));
```

while this command executes successfully, enabling the dialer softphone to start listening while in the background it keeps on ringing the other softphone, and meanwhile the dial timeout and call ends.

Comment: Freeswitch behaves exactly as it should. You have misunderstanding how SIP protocol works, because call can be answered only if callee replies.

Comment: could please tell me how to answer a call on the callee behave using ESL API as in have callee uuid also, I tried to use that uuid in the 'answer' command, it responds 'ok' but nothing happens the call was still ringing.

Comment: Hi, you can't answer a call without callee doing this. Freeswitch behaves correctly when it answer A leg of call, part caller=>freeswitch. Freeswitch=>callee can be answered only by callee. Take a look how simple SIP call looks. INVITE, 180/183, 200OK and etc. 200 OK can be sent out only from callee.You can't tell freeswitch to trigger 200ok from callee.